# border for d3 stack bar chart on selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Trying to implement border for selected bar in d3 stack bar chart. Here the first bar's top border goes behind second bar a little bit. How to avoid this?

```
var svg, height, width, margin, parentWidth, parentHeight;

// container size
parentWidth = 700;
parentHeight = 500;
margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 30};
width = parentWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
height = parentHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var selectedSection = window.sessionStorage.getItem('selectedSection');

// data
var dataset = [{"label":"DEC","Set Up":{"count":12,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2016","graphType":"setup"},"Not Set Up":{"count":12,"id":0,"label":"Not Set Up","year":"2016","graphType":"setup"}},{"label":"JAN","Set Up":{"count":6,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"},"Not Set Up":{"count":21,"id":0,"label":"Not Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}},{"label":"FEB","Set Up":{"count":1,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"},"Not Set Up":{"count":2,"id":0,"label":"Not Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}},{"label":"MAR","Set Up":{"count":0,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"},"Not Set Up":{"count":0,"id":0,"label":"Not Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}},{"label":"APR","Set Up":{"count":0,"id":1,"label":"Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"},"Not Set Up":{"count":0,"id":0,"label":"Not Set Up","year":"2017","graphType":"setup"}}];

// x cord
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2);

// color helper
var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(colorRange.range());

// x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom');

var colors = ['#50BEE9', '#30738C'];

// Set SVG
svg = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom )
  .attr('class', 'setup')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

color.domain(d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== 'label'; }));

dataset.forEach(function(d) {
  var y0 = 0;
  d.values = color.domain().map(function(name) { 
    return {
      name: name, 
      y0: y0, 
      y1: y0 += +d[name].count, 
      patientStatus:d[name].id,
      graphType:d[name].graphType,  
      fromDate:{
        month:d.label,
        year:d[name].year
      },
      toDate:{
        month:d.label,
        year:d[name].year
      }  
    }; 
  });
  d.total = d.values[d.values.length - 1].y1;
});

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  
    return d.total;
  })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var ticks = y.ticks(),
    lastTick = ticks[ticks.length-1];    
var newLastTick = lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]);  
if (lastTick<y.domain()[1]){
  ticks.push(lastTick + (ticks[1] - ticks[0]));
}

// adjust domain for further value
y.domain([y.domain()[0], newLastTick]);

// y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0) 
    .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
    .tickValues(ticks);

x.domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis);

var bar = svg.selectAll('.label')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'g')
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return i;
  })
    .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + x(d.label) + ',0)'; });

var barEnter = bar.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter();

barEnter.append('rect')
  .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
  .attr('y', function(d) { 
    return y(d.y1); 
    })
  .attr('class', function(d, i){
    return 'bar';
    })
  .attr('height', function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  .style('fill', function(d,i) { return colors[i]; })
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    d3.selectAll('.bar').classed('selected', false);
    d3.select(this)
      .classed('bar selected', true);  
    });

barEnter.append('text')
  .text(function(d) { 
    var calcH = y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
    var inText = (d.y1-d.y0);
    if(calcH >= 20) {
      return inText;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
})
.attr('class','inner-text')
.attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.y1)+(y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))/2 + 5; })
.attr('x', function(){
  return (x.rangeBand()/2) - 10;
}); 

svg
  .select('.y')
  .selectAll('.tick')
  .filter(function (d) { 
    return d % 1 !== 0;    
    })
  .style('display','none');

svg
  .select('.y')
  .selectAll('.tick')
  .filter(function (d) { 
    return d === 0;    
    })
  .select('text')
  .style('display','none');
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/559vmhxg/1/)**

[**JSFiddle with d3 v4**](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/ju04x49c/1/)

Comment: That's the normal behaviour, since in a SVG who's painted last stays on top. If you're using D3 v4.x, this could be solved with just one line...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a SVG, just like a real painter putting ink to a white canvas, the element that is painted last stays on top.

Right now, the behaviour you're seeing is the expected one, because each stacked bar (rectangle) is in a different `<g>` element, and the groups, of course, have a given order in the SVG structure.

The solution involves just one line:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).raise();
```

What this line does is selecting the group of the clicked rectangle and raising it (that is, moving it **down** in the DOM tree), so that group will be on top of all others. According to the API, [raise()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_raise):

> Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the **last** child of its parent. (emphasis mine)

*"Moving down"*, *"be on top"* and *"be the last child"* may be a bit confusing and seem contradictory, but here is the explanation. Given this SVG structure:

```
<svg>
    <foo></foo>
    <bar></bar>
    <baz></baz>
</svg>
```

`<baz>`, being the last element, is the one painted **last**, and it is the element visually on the top in the SVG. So, *raising* an element means moving it **down** in the SVG tree structure, but moving it **up** visually speaking.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/86Lgaupt/

PS: I increased the stroke-width just to make visibly clear that the clicked rectangle is now on top.

Answer (score 0):

Tag:

```
  <div id='stacked-bar'></div>
```

Script:

```
    var initStackedBarChart = {
    draw: function(config) {
        me = this,
        domEle = config.element,
        stackKey = config.key,
        data = config.data,
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%Y"),
        width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1),
        yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20),
        xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")),
        yAxis =  d3.axisLeft(yScale),
        svg = d3.select("#"+domEle).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top+10 + margin.bottom+10)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var stack = d3.stack()
            .keys(stackKey)
            .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
            .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

        var layers= stack(data);
            data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });
            xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }));
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) { return d[0] + d[1]; }) ]).nice();

        var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "layer")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

          layer.selectAll("rect")
              .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter().append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'bar')
              .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.data.date)); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]) -1; })
              .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
        .on('click', function(d, i) {
          d3.selectAll('.bar').classed('selected', false);
          d3.select(this).classed('selected', true);
        });

            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+5) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(yAxis);                           
    }
}
var data = [
{"date":"4/1854","total":45,"disease":12,"wounds":14,"other":25},
{"date":"5/1854","total":23,"disease":12,"wounds":0,"other":9},
{"date":"6/1854","total":38,"disease":11,"wounds":0,"other":6},
{"date":"7/1854","total":26,"disease":11,"wounds":8,"other":7}
];
var key = ["wounds", "other", "disease"];
initStackedBarChart.draw({
    data: data,
    key: key,
    element: 'stacked-bar'
});
```

Css:

```
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
.path-line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
svg {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.selected{
  stroke:#333;
  stroke-width:2;

}
```